# Склонение фамилии

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Для правильного оформления документов, хотелось бы узнать склоняется ли Фамилия Москалец

Comment: В женском варианте не склоняется. Если интересует мужской, то уточните, пожалуйста, место ударения - это может влиять на один из падежей.

Comment: Дублирует вопрос http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/422877/