# Склонение мужской фамилии Москалец

Tags: склонение-фамилий

При оформлении документов чтобы не допустить ошибки при склонении мужской фамилии Москалец

Comment: Если с выпаданием гласной буквы, то ни как не может быть там мягкий знак, но это я так думаю, но не уверена, мне как кажется что это фамилия не скланяется, ни один учитель русского языка мне точно не ответил, у всех разное мнение

Comment: "Если с выпаданием гласной буквы, то ни как не может быть там мягкий знак," - нет вы путаете. Или учитель путает. Если выпадает О, то да, мягкого знака быть не может. А вот при выпадении Е - вполне если основа - на мягкий согласный, в данном случае - "москаль". Ну а что учителя не знаю, что все мужские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный склоняются - это стыд. Это точно были учителя русского?

Answer (score 1):

Мужские фамилии на -ец традиционно склоняются с выпадением гласной (как "молодец" или "варенец").

И. Москалец
Р. Москальца
Д. Москальцу
В. Москальца
Т. Москальцом
П. (О) Москальце

Окончание творительного падежа зависит от ударения в исходной форме, если оно падает на суффикс "-ец" (а так обычно и бывает), то при склонении переходит на окончание, поэтому окончание -ом.